# speed up Mysql query searching

Tags: mysql

We have a mysql data table which has 10 years old. For each query, it will search data from 2005 to 2015. However, the most useful data for me will be the recently days or weeks. Is that possible using some command to ask the query search from the end of table.

For example,

```
select *from Portions where Date="20151126" limit 5;
```

This simply query takes ages to run.

Comment: What is the data type of the `Date` column? From the string format of your query, it looks like it may be a varchar type rather than a proper `DATE/DATETIME` type. If you can convert it to a real date type with an index, using it in `ORDER BY` will be very fast.

Comment: If for some reason it is not possible to change the data type (though you really should) if the strings in that column are consistently formatted YYYYMMDD, then just creating an index on it as a varchar column will allow you to sort quickly, but you'll gain no benefits from MySQL's built-in date handling functions.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski, it's int(11). Do you mean I need to sort the whole table? I tried **ORDER BY Date** and it also takes time to run.

Comment: Do you have an index on the date column?

Comment: To create an index, you would use `ALTER TABLE Portions ADD INDEX (Date)`.  Then using `ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 5` for recent items would be significantly faster. It is better to change it to a `DATE` type though, which is done by adding a new `DATE` column and performing an `UPDATE` to do the conversion into it then removing the old column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, check the structure of your database. It may be that you've saved dates as a `VARCHAR` whereas they should be being saved as `DATE`.

The next important part is ensuring you have a primary key on your table which should be of `INT` type and is your primary key. You should also make this auto increment so that it keeps unique IDs of your table. Here's the structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `portions`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for table `portions`
--
ALTER TABLE `portions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `portions`
--
ALTER TABLE `portions`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Ensure this structure is correct and query using the correct syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM `portions` WHERE `date` = '2015-11-26' LIMIT 5;
```

Now, you should find your queries are much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using **materialized view** in this scenario. See [here](http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-materialized-views#what_is) if you want to use it.